# Use C# variable out of method where it is declared

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, methods, public

I don't have that much experience in C# scripting. So please bear with me. As part of an university project I'm working on a given unity project inclusive C# scripts. In my work assignment I need to work with the variable `pelvisPos` (you can see the picture link below). It is necessary to use it in the external method `public void getResults()`. But there it is not possible to reference on the first declaration. Can you help me and give me an approach how I am able to use this variable in my method `public void getResults()`? I look forward to your feedback!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJir5.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture. Include it in the question so it's clear for everyone to read and makes it easier for people to copy and test your code. That said just declare it outside the method (inside the class) and both methods of that class should have access to it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make that variable a class property/field, more or less like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
  private Vector3 pelivsPos;


  private int findClosestTrackedBody(BackgroundData trackerFrameData)
  {
    ...

     pelivsPos = new Vector3(...); // rest goes the same
 }

 public void getResults()
 {
  Debug.Log("Pelivs:" + pelivsPos); // now you can access that field
  }
}
```

Just keep in mind that you will have to call `findClosestTrackedBody` before `getResults`

And also this line: `Debug.Log("Pelivs:" + pelivsPos);` it will only display that value to `Debug` if the `Vector3` class has a `public override string ToString()` method implemented